# Calculation of Cost function in Neural Network Getting NaN or Inf

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, octave, backpropagation

I am trying to calculate costFunction of Neural Network as a part of my programming assignment, using this function.
[image]

Where K is number of Labels. hTheta and y are matrices both of size (5000,10), since I have 5000 training examples and 10 labels. I am using octave and ***I get my cost function as NaN***. (This is expected too, since all the values of hTheta and Y are either 0s or 1s, log(0)*0 would be not defined).

But then how should I then compute the Cost?

Note - hTheta is generated by feedforward algo on neural net and y is input labels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here *Y<sup>i</sup>* can be 1 or 0, but h<sup>i</sup> cannot be 0 or 1. This is because if you are using sigmoid logisitic function, then ontaining 0( or 1) would require argument of sigmoid function to be -infinity (or +infinity), which is not possible. One possible reason may be you must have choosen the learning rate to be too high. Try reducing the learning rate. This worked for me when I had encountered the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

A general recipe to reliably prevent this from happening is to either clip your value or add a small value epsilon `e=10e-6` (or something similar) so that you always have `log(x+e)` with `x+e != 0`. Depending on what exactly you're doing you might then also need to clip `x` to be between `e` and 1. If you combine your `log`s into a fraction within a single `log`, you'd again add `e` in the denominator to avoid any division by zero.

Preventing any NAN-behavior is better than trying to avoid it. With RNNs for example you can have exploding gradients - a situation which is usually out of your control regarding the choice of your hyperparameters - leading to `x=infinity` which then produces NANs if not captured.